# Image generating problem with PHP form a class

Tags: php, class, header, gd

i wrote this code:

```
class Generate{
    private $canvas;
    function __construct($width, $height){
        $this->canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    }
    public function bg($r=0,$g=0,$b=0){
        $color = imagecolorallocate($this->canvas, $r, $g, $b);
        imagefill($this->canvas, 0, 0, $color);
    }
    public function gen(){
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($this->canvas, NULL, 9);
        imagedestroy($this->canvas);
    }
}
```

and called it with this:

```
$G = new Generate(100, 100);
$G->bg(255, 255, 255);
$G->gen();
```

its generating image fine when i comment out the header in the gen() function and set it to save the image. Like this:

```
imagepng($this->canvas, 'img.png', 9);
```

but i want it to send the header(output the image) but it gives me an error. can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? can you even send headers with-in a PHP class?

this code works fine when i don't use OOP

Comment: So you want to save the image, and output it as well?

Comment: You did not tell us what is happening when you don't comment it out.

Comment: You can call the `header` function anywhere you like - in or outside of classes. The only problem is when output has already been generated, than a call to `header` will give a warning. I dunno if the warning is your problem here. But `header` can be used inside classes, that's for sure.

Comment: please remember that header() only works if **nothing** else has been printed to the page yet (like `<meta/><head></head><body...>`)

Comment: How is your current code, sending the header first, then outputting the image not working?  What is the problem?

Comment: it works fine when i don't send the header and just save the image... but given an error when i send the header.

Comment: i do know that you can send headers anywhere and nothing else has been outputted before the header in this code so why is this not working... it works fine when i take it out of the class

Comment: I tried your code on a fresh blank page and it worked fine for me,  the header shows the page is a png image and I can see the (white) image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, you can.  You can send headers at any time **before you send any output to the client**, which I suspect is what your issue is.

You can also check the encoding that you're saving your file in.  If you are saving your file as UTF-8, make sure you save it without a byte order mark.  This counts as output, and will always be the first character in your file meaning any call to `header()` will generate a warning.

Comment: no you got it wrong... the point is not the header() its about why its giving an error... this code works fine if i don't use OOP

Comment: Your question is: "can you even send headers with-in a PHP class?"  The answer is yes.  Perhaps you should clarify your question a bit more then, or at the very least provide the specific error message your are getting?

Answer (score 2):

The code works perfectly for me when I run it as you posted it; are you sure that you aren't just losing your 100x100 white image on a white background?  Try changing the color to, say, `127,255,255` (a lovely aqua) and see if it shows up.